# How do I compare the values mapped to keys in a dictionary with elements in list to avoid redundancy?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I currently have a list which stores the URLs that I have read from a file. I then made a dictionary by mapping those URLs to a simple key (0,1,2,3, etc.).
Now I want to make sure that if the same URL shows up again that it doesn't get mapped to a different key. So I am trying to make a conditional statement to check for that. Basically I want to check if the item in the list( the URL) is the same as the value of any of the keys in the dictionary. If it is I don't want to add it again since that would be redundant. 
I'm not sure what to put inside the if conditional statement for this to work.

```
pairs = {}  #my dictionary
for i in list1:
     if ( i == t for t in pairs ):
        i = i +1
     else:
        pairs[j] = i
        j = j + 1
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for.  It adds the unique values to `pairs`, numbering them starting at zero.  Duplicate values are ignored and do not affect the numbering:

```
pairs = {}
v = 0
for k in list1:
    if k not in pairs:
        pairs[k] = v
        v += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To map items in a list to increasing integer keys there's this delightful idiom, which uses a `collections.defaultdict` with its own length as a default factory

```
import collections

map = collections.defaultdict()
items =  'aaaabdcdvsaafvggddd'
map.default_factory = map.__len__

for x in items:
    map[x]

print(map)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all values in your dict (pairs) by a simple `pairs.values()`. In your `if` condition, you can just add another condition that checks if the new item already exists in the values of your dictionary.

Comment: If the list of URLs you are trying to convert to a dict is static i.e. this is a one time action, you can get rid of the duplicates first (a simple way is to convert your `list` to a `set`), and then create your dict. Assuming the order of the URLs does not matter, as is apparent from your post "mapping those URLs to a simple key".

    `pairs = {k:v for k, v in enumerate(set(URL_list))}`